# 8 Queens Algorithm: Not getting full result set

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, n-queens

Below is my attempt at printing all the solutions of the 8 queens problem (place 8 queens on a chessboard such that none of them are attacking each other). However, this solution is only printing 4 answers, whereas 92 should exist. Anyone see what's wrong?

```
static int[][] visited = new int[8][8];
static int[][] board = new int[8][8];
static int numQueens = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //call recursive method from every starting position            
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                putQueens(board, i, j);
                //clear board and visited array, as well as numQueens
                for(int i2=0; i2<8; i2++){
                    for(int j2=0; j2<8; j2++){
                        board[i2][j2]=0;
                        visited[i2][j2]=0;
                    }
                }
                numQueens=0;
            }
        }
}

static void putQueens(int[][]board, int row, int col){

        if(visited[row][col]==1)
            return;
        visited[row][col]=1;
        boolean hasQueen = false;
            //check columns
        for(int j=0; j<board[0].length; j++){
            if(board[row][j]==1)
                hasQueen = true;
        }
            //check rows
        for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
            if(board[i][col]==1)
                hasQueen = true;

        }
            //check diagonals
        for(int i=row; i<board.length; i++){
            if(col+(i-row)<=7){

                if(board[i][col+(i-row)]==1)
                    hasQueen=true;
            }

        }    
            //check diagonals

        for(int i=row; i>=0; i--){
            if(col-(row-i)>=0){
                if(board[i][col-(row-i)]==1)
                    hasQueen=true;
            }
        }                    
            //check diagonals
        for(int i=row; i<board.length; i++){
            if(col-(i-row)>=0){    
                if(board[i][col-(i-row)]==1)
                    hasQueen=true;
            }

        }
            //check diagonals

        for(int i=row; i>=0; i--){
            if(col+(row-i)<=7){
                if(board[i][col+(row-i)]==1)
                    hasQueen=true;
            }
        }
            //print if solution
        if(!hasQueen){
            board[row][col] = 1;
            numQueens++;

            if(numQueens==8){
                System.out.println("==========");
                for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                        System.out.print(String.format("%3s", board[i][j]));
                        board[i][j]=0;
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                }
                numQueens=0;


            }

        }

        //recurse
        if(row!=7)
            putQueens(board, row+1, col);
        if(col!=7)  
            putQueens(board, row, col+1);
        if(row!=0)
            putQueens(board, row-1, col);
        if(col!=0)
            putQueens(board, row, col-1);


    }
```

Comment: Variables `numQueens`, `board` and `visited` have not been declared. Can you add them to your code along with representative assignments?

Comment: Your recursive algorithm does not include any back-tracking.  Meaning you don't try alternative locations for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. queens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never get all of the combinations since your algorithm is wrong. Here is want you do.  From every board cell you start exploring neighboring cells in BFS fashion and put queen whenever you can. After your board is completed you print it out and wipe it out afterwards. Notice that your approach does not consider every possible option and for every cell you will at at most 1 solution (most 64 in total). Just do a simple backtracking approach.  [Here](http://algoriddles.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/kill-backtrack-n-queen-problem-of-chess/)'s sample implementation.